# Zoom and Pan on a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsarray, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a simple application which consists of a `UITableViewController` with cells of `Languages`. When the user clicks a specific language, it brings up a `UIPageViewController` to show horizontally, 6 images in a pageView. That part is working really well and the images are loading.

I have implemented this, using this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-scrollstyle-with-uipageviewcontroller--mobile-13551.

I would like to achieve a zoom and pan functionality within this as well now.

I have zoom working with the following code.

```
CGFloat scale = pinchRecognizer.scale;
self.pageViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.pageViewController.view.transform, scale, scale);
pinchRecognizer.scale = 1.0;
```

The problem is that the zoom is always in the centre of the image with no way to pan around the image like you can in a normal Photo on an iOS device.

I have found lots of good tutorials on how to achieve this, like http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/07/07/tutorial-all-about-images-part-2-panning-zooming-with-uiscrollview/ as an example. However, my confusion stems from the very first part.

I am loading my `UIPageViewController` using a `NSArray`:

```
self.modelArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"3facts-english-page1.jpg"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"3facts-english-page2.jpg"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"3facts-english-page3.jpg"], nil];
```

How to I extract each image into a `UIImageView`?

I can see that fundamentally, I need to have most of this code to enable the Pan:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"KinkakuJi"];

self.imageView.image = image;
[self.imageView sizeToFit];

self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
```

In my case however, I'm not loading a single `UIImage` but rather a `NSArray`. How do I extract the UIImage from the `NSArray` to make this pan happen?

Any thoughts on this would really be appreciated.